# The role of do in a declarative sentence

Tags: do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

What is the role of "do" in the following sentence?

> Only in the jungle do you find lizards that can soar like dragons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a negative adverbial phrase is placed at the beginning of the clause it modifies, the modified clause is 'marked' just like a question with subject/auxiliary inversion and *do* support.

> **I have** never in my life experienced such terror. →
>   Never in my life **have I** experienced such terror.

In this case, the *only* is equivalent to *not unless*, so the fronted phrase is treated as a negative.

> **You find** lizards that can soar like dragons only in the jungle. →
>   Only in the jungle **do you find** lizards that can soar like dragons.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also found this link http://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-88760.php

Comment: Is 'marking' a linguistic term for subject/auxiliary inversion?

Comment: "Never in my life,  I have experienced such terror."  is considered incorrect?