# When should I use "do" like this: "...but very rarely DO you get to see inside the box"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

From the sentence:

> They are nice and flashy on the outside, and they tell you all the great things that are inside but very rarely **do** you actually get to see inside the box.

I feel natural that the "do" is placed here, but what is this situation called and how do I know when to use it?

Comment: It's a stylised "literary inversion" from the "default" word order: *...but **you very rarely** actually get to see inside the box*. In this particular case, that inversion *also* requires including "do-support" for the verb, but this isn't always the case with literary inversion. And it's got no particular implications for the meaning, either. Just accept it as valid if you come acrosss this kind of thing - but unless you're *very* confident, you probably shouldn't try to copy the style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the function of "do" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165988/what-is-the-function-of-do-in-this-sentence) Also [The role of do in a declarative sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126876/) and possibly others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is a good question and I find your advice a bit off putting. Also, why don't you submit a formal answer?

Comment: @Lambie: It's so obviously a duplicate I don't understand why you went to the trouble of writing *another* answer. I've no idea why you think my advice is "off-putting", but that's presumably your problem, not mine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, it isn't a duplicate as the answers do not explain that certain adverbs trigger it **due to their position** before the verb. to pre-position certain adverbs, you need the auxiliary. And by the way, you don't explain that either.

Comment: The inversion isn't "triggered" by the fact of there being any particular adverb (with or without intensifiers such as ***very*** and ***actually***). So for my money, *your* answer is potentially misleading because (especially, in combination with your comments) it gives the impression that the learner *should* introduce inversion if he happens to use ***rarely***. Which is obviously nonsense - it's a stylised literary device that statistically speaking occurs rarely, compared to the default English word order.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I explained it and showed how it can be avoided. ERGO, I am not suggesting it be used. It's triggered by the type of adverb and the fact it precedes the verb, which the answers did not state nor did you.

Answer (score 3):

> *They are nice and flashy on the outside, and they tell you all the*
> *great things that are inside* but [*very rarely do you actually get to*
> *see inside the box*].

The bracketed element has subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs in declarative clauses only when certain types of element are put in front position. Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted:

> *Never had I seen such chaos.*
>
> *At no stage were they in danger*.

"Rarely" is not negative, but it is semantically close to a negative, in that *Rarely do I leave the house*, for example, entails that I don't often leave the house, that I do leave the house no more often than occasionally", and in this respect has a negative meaning.

The other 'approximate negators' are the adverbs "seldom", "barely", "hardly" and "scarcely", and the determinatives "few" and "little".

Answer (score 1):

**This is a subject-auxiliary inversion**

In English grammar, subject-auxiliary inversion is the movement of an auxiliary verb to a position in front of the subject of a main clause.

Two possibilities:

- but **very rarely do you actually get to see** inside the box.
  OR
- but **you actually rarely get to see** inside the box.

It is the placement of the adverb **rarely** that triggers the inversion; if the adverb is placed after the verb phrase "get to see", the inversion would not be necessary.

[inversion](https://www.thoughtco.com/subject-auxiliary-inversion-1692003)

It is adverbs such as rarely, seldom, little that work like this. Refer to the link for more of them. Not all adverbs do.